# How to execute all commands without prefix for only some users discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
 if (message.author === ownerID && Message.content.match(command))
```

After this what should I do to execute the command without prefix

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these by using your `index.js` or `bot.js`, without using any `prefix` for example:

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("Your_Command_Name")) {
        message.channel.send("This command is working.")
    }
})
```

The `client` can be `bot` depends on how you call your bot on your `index/bot.js`